# Groupby, select EF Ccore 3.1

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have three tables like this:

```
public partial class PriceSite
{
    public DateTime ValidFromGmtDtm { get; set; }        
    public long PriceSiteId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PriceSiteProduct> PriceSiteProduct { get; set; }
}

public partial class PriceSiteProduct
{
    public long PriceSiteId { get; set; }
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }     
}

public partial class Product
{
    public string ProductCd { get; set; }
    public string ProductNm { get; set; }       
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PriceSiteProduct> PriceSiteProduct { get; set; }
}
```

We need to group the data by `Productname` and choose the product with highest `ValidFromGmtDtm` (`Pricesite`).

I tried this query

```
using (var dbContext = _dbContextProvider.DbContext)
{
    var data = from t1 in dbContext.PriceSite
               join t2 in dbContext.PriceSiteProduct 
                           on t1.PriceSiteId equals t2.PriceSiteId
               join t3 in dbContext.Product
                           on t2.ProductId equals t3.ProductId
               where t1.ValidFromGmtDtm > shellSiteNotification.ValidFromDtm
               select new
                      {
                          PriceSiteId = t1.PriceSiteId,
                          ValidFrom = t1.ValidFromGmtDtm,
                          ProductId = t3.ProductId,
                          ProductNm = t3.ProductNm,
                          ProductValues = t3.PumpPriceProduct
                      };

    var res1 = data.ToList();

    var data2 = from element in res1
                group element by element.ProductNm into groups
                select groups.OrderByDescending(p => p.ValidFrom).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I am getting timeout error by running this query.

I also tried this query:

```
var grouped = from priceSite in _dbContextProvider.DbContext.PriceSite
              where priceSite.ValidFromGmtDtm < shellSiteNotification.ValidFromDtm
              from priceSiteProduct in priceSite.PriceSiteProduct
              group priceSiteProduct by priceSiteProduct.Product.ProductNm into produtGroup
              select new
                     {
                          ProductNamKey = produtGroup.Key,
                          produtGroup = produtGroup.OrderByDescending(x => x.PriceSite.ValidFromGmtDtm)
                     };
```

This code throws a runtime error as we cannot access the navigation property in select in EF Core.

I also tried another query - but this also results in a timeout

```
var result = from s in _dbContextProvider.FreshReadOnlyPricingDbContext.PriceSite
             from r in s.PriceSiteProduct
             let p = r.Product
             select new
                    {
                        PriceSiteId = s.PriceSiteId,
                        ValidFrom = s.ValidFromGmtDtm,
                        ProductId = p.ProductId,
                        ProductNm = p.ProductNm,
                        ProductValues = p.PumpPriceProduct
                    };
    
var list = result.ToList();
```

Comment: how many records do you have in your database ?

Comment: @AliReza 2221018 IN PRICESITE , 7914016 IN PRICESITEPRODUCT AND 100 in product

Comment: what your method returns? list or object?

Comment: 60 percent of you problem is your database. you are trying to group some data in 7milion record so its normal if its slow and end up with timeout .
first try to add some indexes your destination columns that you want to group
second try to add some filtering in your queries to eliminate extra data that probably you don't need.

Comment: also you can change timeout time in your connection string. TimeOut=120; depending you database connection string supported format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is known EF and SQL limitation, you cannot get items after grouping. Only `Key` and aggregation result is supported. So basically EF proposes to put `ToList()` before grouping and it means that you will load several million records to the client.

Without third party extensions which can do that effectively, you can use the following workaround:

```cs
using (var dbContext = _dbContextProvider.DbContext)
{
    var dataQuery = 
        from t1 in dbContext.PriceSite
        join t2 in dbContext.PriceSiteProduct 
                    on t1.PriceSiteId equals t2.PriceSiteId
        join t3 in dbContext.Product
                    on t2.ProductId equals t3.ProductId
        where t1.ValidFromGmtDtm > shellSiteNotification.ValidFromDtm
        select new
        {
            PriceSiteId = t1.PriceSiteId,
            ValidFrom = t1.ValidFromGmtDtm,
            ProductId = t3.ProductId,
            ProductNm = t3.ProductNm,
            ProductValues = t3.PumpPriceProduct
        };

    var query = 
        from key in dataQuery.Select(d => new { d.ProductNm }).Distinct()
        from d in dataQuery.Where(d => d.ProductNm == key.ProductNm)
            .OrderByDescending(d => d.ValidFrom)
            .Take(1)
        select d; 

    var result = query.ToList();
}
```